# Need to find missing column value by comparing from 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

```
DF1:  A   B
      1   a
      2   b
      3   c
      4   d
      5   e

DF2:  A   B
      1   a
      2   b
      3   c

Expect Result:   A  B
                 4  d
                 5  e
```

Tried Join & Map but not getting desired result.

Please guide to find solution.

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework. However, try writing down steps in your own language that describe what to do. If anyone can follow these steps without guessing, they describe the algorithm sufficiently, then you only have to translate it to Python.

Comment: What result are you getting? How are you implementing join and map? What does your code look like? We won't code for you, but we will help clear up specific issues that you are having with the commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also works :

```
df1.loc[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])]
Out[34]:
    A   B
3   4   d
4   5   e
```

Answer (score 2):

`concat` and `drop_duplicates`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
Out[789]: 
   A  B
3  4  d
4  5  e
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna()
```

Outputs:

```
   A  B
3  4  d 
4  5  e
```